# Typescript union type inside a interface function declaration

Tags: typescript

```
Type '(param: CountryCodeItem) => void' is not assignable to type '(param: Item) => void'.
 Types of parameters 'param' and 'param' are incompatible.
   Type 'Item' is not assignable to type 'CountryCodeItem'.
     Type 'BasicItem' is missing the following properties from type 'CountryCodeItem': abbreviation, code(2322)
```

Not able to understand why I am getting the above error? Even though if the error is happening then why only in Case 1 not in case 2 in below-specified example

Case 1: Function definition inside interface via arrow function leading to error

Case 3: Instead of arrow function definition used classic way of defining the function and it is working fine

```js
export interface CountryCodeItem {
    id: number;
    label: string;
    abbreviation: string;
    code: number;
}

interface BasicItem {
    label: string;
    id: number;
}

export type Item = BasicItem | CountryCodeItem;

//Case 1 
interface Case1 {
  fn : (param:Item)=>void
}

const case1 :Case1 =  {
  fn :(param: CountryCodeItem) => {
  console.log("a")
}
}

//Case 2
const case2Fn=(a: Item) => {
  console.log("a")
}
const abc: CountryCodeItem= {
    id: 10,
  label: "a",
  abbreviation: "a",
  code:10
    
}
case2Fn(abc)

//Case 3
interface Case3 {
  fn(param:Item):void
}

const case3 :Case3 =  {
  fn :(param: CountryCodeItem) => {
  console.log("a")
}
}
```

PlayGround Link [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-5KnAPZgyE6XdR0MgBp5hngLdb+VMnksVuseDs9kzMocWacetaeNmfpxc9MePmXvV3uRuWTNn9TlSgaDwZCZYyMs4gA)

Answer (score 0):

Case1 is Inherit the interface. So type must be same. so below code is correct because Item is same as BasicItem | CountryCodeItem.

```js
const case1 :Case1 =  {
  fn :(param: BasicItem | CountryCodeItem) => {
  console.log("a")
}
}
```

Case2 is function argument. So argument only needs toBasicItem or CountryCodeItem.

Comment: Then why Case 1 is working fine when I am using intersection instead of union.[PlayGround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgYQgFcUoBPQgE2AElUBbOAbwFgAoOTxSgLjiSL0ARmgDc7LnAA2mEVL4BnGFGQBzcRy6yhUYADcEmGAghJFytRsnYI1PgOFj2AX3btkqDDjwAhTAoRsOmBGVk1OGTlzFSR1CS4EXn5BESgNVzZ2UEhYOBgyMDxgxgBeOD8AoIY4ADICYlIKW1oGDXYAenb8fzwARncUNCxcAh7e5nj0JDg+AAowTChMeh5igEoSgD49CESXNzYbJCU4bDGZ7oVgcbKJzSmZ+cXlvkISZSbqdbgtu84jhQQKTAAB0UggqlmACJMFC1vs2BkOl0enAAEzsAHwM5XNEAMSQJVmmD431+YX+pkBwLBEOhsPhiMxVPgsmwrwaHyoLRCZQpCSSvQADAAaeKRYDyOAwqFizTaXQGIwmMzS2Fyyl2YXxTgInHAfFIYlCbBrIA)

Comment: Interface need to accept both type. argument need to accept one or the other type.
If case1 param is only accept CountryCodeItem, even if CountryCodeItem include all BasicItem keys.TypeScript can't understand this.

Comment: understand is mistake. CountryCodeItem has abbreviation and code. so if abbreviation is comming, Typescript can't proceed code.

Comment: I have updated the question and added case 3. Can you justify case 3?